# how to convert a string like "Sat Mar 17 11:27:57 +0000 2012" into date in R

Tags: r, date

The question is like the title:

The date date i got is in the format like "Sat Mar 17 11:27:57 +0000 2012". 
How could i convert it into R's date data?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to specify the correct format (as documented in `strptime`):

```
fmt <- "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"
# POSIXct
as.POSIXct("Sat Mar 17 11:27:57 +0000 2012", format=fmt, tz="UTC") 
[1] "2012-03-17 11:27:57 UTC"
# POSIXlt
strptime("Sat Mar 17 11:27:57 +0000 2012", format=fmt, tz="UTC")
[1] "2012-03-17 16:27:57 UTC"
```